# Enum Property callback forces scene update

Tags: python, scripting, add-on, properties

I have an enum property and a callback function defined like so:

```
def asset_callback(scene, context):

    # Function that return properly formatted list of items
    items = get_assets()

    return items

class PipelineProperties(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):

    asset_categories = bpy.props.EnumProperty(
        name="Asset Categories",
        description="Categories for Project Specific Assets",
        items=asset_callback
    )
```

Setting up my Enum Property with a function meant to generate a dynamic list and populate the enum with this list, forces scene update continuously. I only want this function to run once, and then I plan on using a persistent handler `bpy.app.handlers.load_post`, only execute the callback after the file is loaded.

Is there a way around the forced scene update trigger on the callback function for an EnumProperty?